# Index, IndexMany, IndexAsnyc, IndexManyAsync with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I try to understand indexing options using nest for ElasticSearch and I executed each of them and here are my results:

```
    var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, defaultIndex: "mydatabase"); 
    settings.SetTimeout(1800000);             
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);  
    var createIndexResult = client.CreateIndex("mydatabase");  
    var mapResult = client.Map<Product>(c => c.MapFromAttributes().SourceField(s=>s.Enabled(true));
```

1) **Index**: When I use Index option by iterating each object, It works smooth although it is slow.

```
foreach (var item in Items)
{
  elasticClient.Index(item);
}
```

2) **IndexAsync**: This worked without any exception but It was not faster than snyc iteration and ***less documents*** were indexed.

```
 foreach (var item in Items)
    {
      elasticClient.IndexAsync(item);
    }
```

3) **IndexMany:** I tried, `elasticClient.IndexMany(items);` without foreach of course, It runs faster than doing foreach -index option, but somehow when I have a lot of data (in my case was 500.000objects) it threw and exception, saying

> "System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: A
>   connection that its continuation was expected, has been closed by the
>   server ..
>       at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ()"

when I check the log file, I can see only

> "2016-01-14
>
> > 10:21:49,567][WARN ][http.netty               ] [Microchip] Caught
> >     exception while handling client http traffic, closing connection [id:
> >     0x68398975, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:57860 => /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9200]"

4)**IndexManyAsync:** `elasticClient.IndexManyAsync(Items);` trying indexasnyc throws similar exception as snyc but I can see more information in the log file.

> [2016-01-14 11:00:16,086][WARN ][http.netty               ]
>   [Microchip] Caught exception while handling client http traffic,
>   closing connection [id: 0x43bca172, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59314 =>
>   /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:9200]
>   org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException:
>   HTTP content length exceeded 104857600 bytes.

My questions are what are the exact differences? in which cases we might need async? why both indexmany and indexmanyasnyc options throw such exception? 
it looks like **index** option is the safest one. Is it just ok to use it like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `sync` or `async` will not have any impact on Elasticsearch indexing performance. You would want to use `async` if you do not want to block your client code on completion of indexing, that's all.

Coming to `Index` vs `IndexMany`, it is always recommended to use the latter to take advantage of batching and avoiding too many request/response cycles between your client and Elasticsearch. That said, you cannot simply index such a huge number of documents in a single request. The exception message is pretty clear in saying that your batch index request has exceeded the HTTP content length limit of 100MB. What you need to do is reduce the number of documents you want to index using `IndexMany` so that you do not hit this limit and then invoke `IndexMany` multiple times till you complete indexing all of 500,000 documents.

Comment: Even I'm facing the same performance issue. Unlike batmaci I dont have so many documents. I have around 40 docs(80mb in total) which I'm trying to index as **attachments**. But it takes a hell lot of time to index . As you said **reduce the number of documents you want to index using IndexMany**, how can I do that? Because right now I'm saving all the docs in a list and using IndexMany i'm passing the list to . TIA

Comment: I know this is an old thread and so this answer is not likely to help ASN, but it might help others. If your List is too large to handle all at once, you want to deal with it as a "Paged List" along the lines of what this project (https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList) helps with. I stumbled upon this question because I'm trying to performance tune our ES, not because I had this issue, but thought I'd try to add something (though I'm sure this is obvious to many).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `indexMany` and `indexManyAsync` is that you are indexing too much data in one request.

This can be solved by doing multiple `indexMany` calls on subsets of your list, but there is now an easier way to deal with this called `bulkAllObservable`

```
var bulkAllObservable = client.BulkAll(items, b => b
    .Index("myindex")
    // how long to wait between retries
    .BackOffTime("30s") 
    // how many retries are attempted if a failure occurs
    .BackOffRetries(2) 
    // refresh the index once the bulk operation completes
    .RefreshOnCompleted()
    // how many concurrent bulk requests to make
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
    // number of items per bulk request
    .Size(1000)
)
// Perform the indexing, waiting up to 15 minutes. 
// Whilst the BulkAll calls are asynchronous this is a blocking operation
.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), next =>
{
    // do something on each response e.g. write number of batches indexed to console
});
```

This will index your whole list in chunks of 1000 items at a time.